# What is Honda HDS HIM?

Tags: honda, obd

I've been trying to find inexpensive PC based ways to connect to the [older Honda's which use the 3-pin OBD connectors](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/36498/reading-obd-data-from-the-old-honda-23-pin-dlc). I have run across a package being sold in various places called [Honda HDS HIM](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2016-wholesale-for-Honda-HDS-Scanner-for-Honda-HIM-HDS-diagnostic-Tool-HDS-for-Honda-Car/32591668521.html?spm=2114.13010308.0.0.VtjBvE).

I was wondering if anyone knows what this is / has experience with this type of system.

**Is this third party-software, an OEM device being licensed by a third-party, or cracked OEM software being resold with third-party hardware?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actullay the picture above is not a Honda HDS HIM interface, it's a Honda MVCI interface.

Honda HDS (Honda & Acura Diagnostic System) is the latest diagnostic software for Honda vehicles. Diagnostic functions available for vehicles of HONDA/ACURA from year 1992 to 2007. Test coverage: Dynamical, Body, Chassis, ABS, SRS, Anti-theft, etc. HDS supports CAN BUS system, and it can re-program the Auto ECU.

HIM is the host with double board (see picture below).

So [Honda HDS](http://www.obdii365.com/wholesale/key-programmer-fly-100-1718.html) is the copied software load on a third-party HIM firmware. You need an RS-232 port on your computer. If your computer doesn't natively have one, you'll need a USB->RS-232 adapter. Software updates frequently.

I have successfully used the TPMS features, CKP relearn, idle relearn, ECU reset, and cleared DTS faults. I belive this thing can data log, reprogram gauge clusters, and reprogram the immobilizer for new keys, but have not tried these things yet.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

HDS HIM stands for Honda Diagnostic System - Honda Interface Module. This is the current HIM. It interfaces with a PC to run scan tool software and is a standalone module reflash unit. It requires a current Honda OEM software subscription to function.

[image: Current HDS HIM]

The device you reference is not an OEM device.  Honda has used at least three interface devices but that is not one of them. The Honda authorized  device costs much more then the amount asked for in the link.

Info on the Honda tools and software susciptions are a available at techinfo.honda.com.  The techinfo site is the official site for OEM scan tool info. Most OEM's are listed there.

Comment: So do you know anything about the software?  Is it hacked OEM software or purely third party?  I see at this link that the Honda software, which only works with their hardware, costs about $1500 per year as a subscription: http://estore.honda.com/service-express/subscriptions.asp

Comment: I have no experience with that product. I have seen poorly done third party and hacked OEM software. I have not found any of it that works better than about 80%. The most common failure is in the "bi-direction controls". I have seen this poorly done type of software cause serious problems but it usually just fails to work or displays incorrect data. The one I saw recently displayed rpm at idle as 16100rpm.  The price you see for the Service Express subscription is correct. I have and use the OEM Honda HDS. It is an excellent product.

Comment: I'm not interested in bidi support, just being able to read/log live sensor data from the old 3 pin connectors, as long as it does that I'm happy.